# Which one should I start the sentence with, “What are” or “What is”?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

I have a question. If you are asked to form a question about the part in bold as in the sentence

> There are **many flowers** in the park.

are you going to say “**What is** in the park?” or “**What are** in the park?

Are they both OK?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the question-asker is aware of at the time the question is asked. Both are OK when the bolded part is unknown, though **what is** is much more common in my experience when the plurality is uncertain. The "default assumption" of English-as-used seems to be the singular case, either assuming a single noun or taking potentially multiple nouns as a single grouping.

If the bolded part is already known when the question is being asked, then **what are** should be preferred to agree with the quantity of the noun.

However, usage is sloppy (at least in the U.S.) and I hear many people that seem to use the singular case exclusively in situations like this. I think that you are unlikely to face any confusion or criticism with either choice, but when in doubt the singular case will probably sound the most natural to a native speaker.

Comment: Agreed, "Q: What **is** in the park?" "A: There **are** many flowers and trees".  The question uses the default singular, but the answer doesn't have to match if the subject is plural.